# How do I overwrite a specific part of a text file in Python?

Tags: python, file

For example if in my text file I have

```
Explosion,Bomb,Duck
Jim,Sam,Daniel
```

and I wanted to change `Daniel` in that file, so that nothing else would be affected. How would I achieve this without overwriting the whole file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fileinput`:

```
import fileinput

with fileinput.FileInput(fileToSearch, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line.replace(textToSearch, textToReplace), end='')
        #testToSearch:- Daniel 
        #textToReplace:- newName
```

Or if you want to keep it more simple, just do the operation in reading from one file and writing the replaced content in a second file. And then overwrite it!

```
f1 = open('orgFile.txt', 'r')
f2 = open('orgFileRep.txt', 'w')
for line in f1:
    f2.write(line.replace('textToSearch', 'textToReplace'), end=' ')
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Comment: I was going to say use `split` and then search each index, but your idea is better and search each

Comment: split would work as well, but that would require more work to be done.

Comment: the read operation if done in f1, then fetch line, use replace function and den write new replaced in f2...in case you want to do it this way..else go for 1st

Comment: @Deca doesn't python permit a `'rw'` object?

Answer (score -2):

if you want get the last element  first you need the  read() method which simply read from files then split it (comma is the seperator ) and using slice [:-1]

Answer (score -2):

```
f = open('name.txt','rb+')
for line in f:
    line.replace('change','Daniel')
    f.write(line)
f.close()
```